# R is not referencing source files correctly

Tags: r

I have a set of `R` files that I want to source in my main program, and am using the `source()` function. These 5 files are all in the same child directory called `reference_r_scripts`

```
source('reference_r_scripts/libraries.R')
source('reference_r_scripts/environment_variables.R')
source('reference_r_scripts/plot_variables.R')
source('reference_r_scripts/static_data.R')
source('reference_r_scripts/functions.R')
```

the first 3 are sourced successfully, but the 4th and 5th cannot be found, which is odd because they are all in the same folder:

```
> source('reference_r_scripts/static_data.R')
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'functions.R': No such file or directory
> source('reference_r_scripts/functions.R')
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'plot_variables.R': No such file or directory
```

just to ensure they are actually all present, `list.files()` produces the correct result:

```
> list.files('reference_r_scripts')
[1] "environment_variables.R" "functions.R"             "libraries.R"             "plot_variables.R"       
[5] "static_data.R"
```

Is there any suggestions to overcome this?

Comment: what happens when you feed `source()` the full name/file path?

Answer (score 0):

Just found.

there was a circular reference in one of the files I was referring to. the `static_data` file was referring to data in the 'functions`file, but the reference to the`functions` file was incorrect

corrected this reference, and that solved the problem